# Visual studio unable to attach to coreCLR. access is denied

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging, coreclr

I have created a console app in Dot.net Core 2.0 and when I run the I am getting Unable to attach to CoreCLR. access is denied

[image]

I have tried, cleaning, deleting files in bin and obj and also tried running under 86x, but could not find any fix for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by installing the *newer version of Dot.Net* which is right now 2.1, in your case it could be different in future.
[image]

You can check newer stable version [On Official Microsoft Site for Dot.net core here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks)

and Original Post [check](https://scientistz.com/forums/topic/solved-visual-studio-unable-to-attach-to-coreclr-access-is-denied/)

Answer (score 30):

In my case (for .net6) I had to change project file from:

```
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
```

To

```
<PublishSingleFile Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">true</PublishSingleFile>
```

Apparently debuger cant handle single exe file.

Comment: Great. This solved the "Unable to attach to CoreCLR. The debugger’s protocol is incompatible with the debuggee" error as well. Thank you!

Comment: Attention JetBrains Rider devs: Rider fails silently for this issue. I didn't see the error message until I loaded VS2022 Community.